# How does Kernel density estimation lead to normalization? Does it at all?

Tags: normalization, kernel-smoothing

I am looking at a report of a company. They are saying they are normalizing data. They have time-series data (i.e. data for certain parameters for sequence of time).
They first generate new variables as $100\cdot(x/lag(x)-1)$
Then they do Kernel density estimation.
I thought normalizing is subtracting mean and dividing by sd, wasn't it?

1) So, is $100\cdot(x/lag(x)-1)$ a normalization for time-series?
EDIT: as I understand this is just calculating the ratio of one year by another year. Is it considered normalization?

2) What is the kernel used for in here then? Just smoothing?

Comment: If you write $lag$, do you mean logarithm $\log$?

Comment: "Normalization" is a very overloaded term -- much like "linear."

Comment: Subtracting the mean and dividing by the SD is usually called *standardization* (although some people overload that term, too).

Comment: @user777, could you clarify what you mean by "overloaded"? Do you mean that there are different meanings to it?

Comment: @user3349993 I mean that there are many meanings of "normalization." It sounds like the company's definition and yours are not the same -- and since companies' procedures tend to be etched in stone, changing their mind will be like shouting into a hurricane. 0-mean, unit variance normalization is one method; but some people "normalize" by putting everything in the $[-1,1]$ or $[0,1]$ intervals. Or they are referring to normalized vectors... Or any of a number of other examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $lag$ is the lagged variable. Somehow $lag(x_t)=x_{t-1}$.

Therefore it is not **normalization** that is performed. They just turn a (price/value?) series into a series of (returns?) ratios : $\tilde{x}_t=\frac{x_t-x_{t-1}}{x_{t-1}}$. The 100 multiplier is just a way to express these ratios in percentage I guess.

Then there is nothing wrong with fitting any distribution on the returns. Kernel estimation is indeed smoother (than producing the empirical distribution).